# PHP - Convert base64 file content to PDF

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have an API in Symfony and a front with React. 
I'm trying to upload documents (jpg, png or pdf) but I only want to store pdf file in my directory. So, when a user send an image, i want to convert it in pdf before uploading.

```
    public function upload($rawData, $extension, $key, &$contentType)
    {
        $rawData = explode(';base64,', $rawData);
        $contentType = substr($rawData[0], 5);
        $rawFileData = $rawData[1];

        if ($extension !== "pdf" && $extension !== "PDF") {
            $tmpDir = '/tmp';
            $image = $tmpDir . '/' . $key . '.' . $extension;
            file_put_contents($image, base64_encode($rawFileData));

            $imagick = new \Imagick();
            $imagick->readImage($image) ;
            $imagick->writeImages($tmpDir. '.pdf', false) ;
        }
    }
```

I've tried with Imagick library but it's give me an error like 'convert : Not a JPEG file'. What's wrong or is it another better library to do it?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: maybe the upload is wrong? if you're using symfony, I wonder why you're going "raw" on this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use finally fpdf and fpdi libraries

```
composer require setasign/fpdf
composer require setasign/fpdi
```

```
 public function upload($rawData, $extension, $key, &$contentType)
 {
     $rawData = explode(';base64,', $rawData);
     $contentType = substr($rawData[0], 5);
     $rawFileData = $rawData[1];

     if ($extension !== "pdf" && $extension !== "PDF") {
         // upload image
         $tmpDir = $this->getParameter('tmpDir');
         $image = $tmpDir . '/' . $key . '.' . $extension;
         file_put_contents($image, base64_decode($rawFileData));

         // create pdf and upload it
         $pdf = new Fpdi();
         $pdf->AddPage();
         $pdfFile = $tmpDir . '/' . $key . '.pdf';
         $pdf->Image($image,0,0,$pdf->GetPageWidth(),$pdf->GetPageHeight());
         $pdf->Output('F', $pdfFile);

         //get pdf raw data
         $data = file_get_contents($pdfFile);
         $rawData = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
         unlink($image);
     }
}
```

My services.yml :

```
parameters:
    tmpDir: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/tmp'
```